# Remove server name from JSESSIONID

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, jsessionid

Our application runs on JBOSS and its front end on Apache. When accessign the URL externally, the JSESSIONID displays the servername within the Content property of the cookie.

Any ideas how this can be removed???

Thanks,

Comment: Which versioj of JBoss? Are you using mod_jk to communicate between Apache and JBoss?

Comment: Hi,

We are using JBOSS 4.3_CP08.

And yes, we are using mod_jk to communicate between the 2.

Answer (score 1):

mod_jk adds the name of the worker to the cookie to remember to which tomcat upcoming request must be directed.

By default, the worker name is equal to the jvmRoute as configured on the tomcat, in the <Engine> tag, in server.xml.

You can change the workers.properties to use another worker name, but you will need to add the jvm_route definition:

```
...
worker.myworker.jvm_route=<jvm-route-as-specified-in-tomcat-conf>
...
```